# Are we going to enable hats in the Android app?

Tags: discussion, android-app, winter-bash-2014

I used Stack Exchange with my laptop and the android app today; however, users who are wearing hats when I use my laptop don't have hats in the Android app.  For instance balpha's hat doesn't show up in the Android app.

Is this expected behavior?  Will the Android app get hat support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the app won't get hats. For a three-week pure fun project it's not worth it to create a second implementation of the hat placement code (we can't use the one from the website as-is) and go through the whole process of testing/releasing an app update.